# How do I make Rails 4 associations automatically save to both tables using has_many / belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

My associations are about 50% working..

I have three tables - Users, Bands, and Bandmemberships

I can pull info from the database in my view from two tables and it works fine..

> @user.bands.each

And when I run commands in the console it saves to the bands database and the bandmemberships database

> user = User.first
>
> user.bands.create(:name => "sample")

However if I run the "preferred" command in the console, it fails:

> user = User.first
>
> user.create_band(:name => "sample")
>
> NoMethodError: undefined method `create_band' for # User:0x007ff0b9182728

But, if I use the bands/new.html.erb form only the band is saved in the database, but nothing in the association table (bandmemberships).  Not sure where to look really but I feel like I'm just missing one line of code somewhere to make it all work

---

**Main View**
views/users/show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "My Dashboard") %>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <%= render @user %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <h4>You are in <%= @user.bands.count %> bands:</h4>
        <% if @user.bands.any? %>
            <% @user.bands.each do |band| %>
                <p><%= render band %></p>
            <% end %>
        <% else %>
            <div>
              <h3>You are not in any bands.</h3>
              <p>Click here to join a band</p>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Bands Controller**
controllers/bands_controller.rb

```
class BandsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @band = Band.new(strong_params)
    if @band.save
      redirect_to @band
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def new
    @band = Band.new

  end

  def show
    @band = Band.find(params[:id])

  end

  private

  def strong_params
    params.require(:band).permit(:name)
  end

end
```

---

**Users Controller**
controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.new(strong_params)
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "You are now signed in"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.bands.build
  end


  private

    def strong_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end


end
```

---

**Users Model**
models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :bandmemberships
  has_many :bands, through: :bandmemberships
  has_many :tours, through: :bands

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bands, :tours

  before_save {self.email = email.downcase }
  before_create :create_remember_token


  validates :firstname,
            presence: true,
            length: { maximum: 50}

  validates :lastname,
            presence: true,
            length: { maximum: 50}

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :email,
            presence: true,
            format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false}

  has_secure_password
  validates :password,
            length: { minimum: 6 }

  def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def User.encrypt(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token)
    end



end
```

---

**Band Model**
models/band.rb

```
class Band < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :bandmemberships
  has_many :users, through: :bandmemberships

  has_many :bandtourmemberships
  has_many :tours, through: :bandtourmemberships

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tours
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users

end
```

---

**Band/User association Model**
models/bandmembership.rb

```
class Bandmembership < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :band

end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `has_many`, you can't use `create_object` as that method doesn't exist.

You'll want to use `user.bands.create(attributes_hash)` in order to create a band associated to a user.

Check out the [AR association docs for `has_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference) for more details on this.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to write that?  Is it in my Band controller?  I'm guessing somehow it uses current_user